# How to show the monthly price of a yearly subscription in StoreKit 2?

Tags: ios, storekit

I can show the total yearly (or 6-month) auto renewable subscription price using [displayPrice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/3749580-displayprice) just fine, but I also want to show how much that would be per month, as I think its more enticing.

I could just use [price](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/3749586-price) and divide by 12 (or 6), but then I wouldn't know how to show the local currency symbol next to the price.

According to my googling this is easy to do in StoreKit 1 using `SKProduct`, but how do I do it in StoreKit 2 using `Product`?

Thanks!

PD: Is there a way to be able to test the different locales to make sure their prices/currency symbols are showing correctly?

Comment: You also have the period as a value to compare agains when calculating the right monthly price to handle possible future changes to the billing period. The price of the product is always in the locale of the app store user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it is annoying that `priceLocale` is not available on the SKProduct object in StoreKit 2. Apparently `priceLocale` was removed in StoreKit 2 because it was not used very often!

To show your monthly price - you are correct - you will have to just use `price` and divide by 12 or 6. That's what they say in their [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/3749586-price):

> Use this property to perform arithmetic calculations with the price of
> the product. For a localized string representation of the price to
> display to customers, use the `displayPrice` property instead.

To know what to show the as local currency symbol next to the price, you will have to rely on `priceFormatStyle` and then extract the [currency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/formatstyle/currency)

As for testing, the only thing I do is to have multiple sandbox testers created with different regions to see the prices displayed in their locale.

But know this - if you are using just `displayPrice` - you have to worry about nothing. The price will always be in the locale of that App Store. These complications come in because you want to perform operations on your price (here - translating it to monthly) and then show it.

Answer (score 1):

We have own function that puts pieces together + you need to have Xcode updated to 15+:

- take currency from [Product](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product) -> [priceFormatStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/4044347-priceformatstyle)
- and base price from [Product](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product) -> [price](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/3749586-price)

Then it's just code stuff (disclaimer this is not Swift code, just for logic):

```js
     case 'MONTH':
        return getFormattedPrice(Number(subscriptionVariant.price), subscriptionVariant.currency)
      case 'YEAR': {
        const perMonthValue = Number(subscriptionVariant.price) / 12
        try {
          const trunc = Math.floor(perMonthValue * 100) / 100
          return getFormattedPrice(trunc, subscriptionVariant.currency)
      ...
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be something like this,

```
let monthlyPriceDecimal = productItem.price.doubleValue/12
self.lblYearly.text = "\(productItem.priceLocale.currencySymbol ?? "") \(String(format: "%.2f", monthlyPriceDecimal)) / Month"
```

Comment: But `Product` (not `SKProduct`) doesn't have a `priceLocale` property. That's the whole point of the question.